# How to recreate an order of events where each row has the current and previous event?

Tags: python, pandas

I have website hit data which for which the timestamp is only accurate to the minute. I would like to recreate the exact order of the hits. I have the previous page path as well as the current path.

Is it possible to recreate the order of events using just the following data in Pandas? Alternatively I can use SQL or something else all together...

I have searched high and wide but have yet to get at all close to solving this, either it is fiendishly difficult, or I am missing the terminology of this kind of problem. Even a hint of what to look for would be much appreciated :)

---

**Original Data**

```
+----+------------------+------+------------+---------------+
| id |    timestamp     | user |    path    | previous_path |
+----+------------------+------+------------+---------------+
|  1 | 19/05/2020 17.38 | a    | 8511p.html | (entrance)    |
|  2 | 19/05/2020 17.39 | a    | 8511p.html | 398s1.html    | <- previous_path = path of row 3
|  3 | 19/05/2020 17.39 | a    | 398s1.html | 8511p.html    | <- previous_path = path of row 1
|  4 | 19/05/2020 17.44 | a    | 398s1.html | 8511p.html    |
|  5 | 19/05/2020 17.46 | a    | 406s1.html | 398s1.html    |
|  6 | 19/05/2020 17.46 | a    | 318c1.html | 406s1.html    |
|  7 | 19/05/2020 17.47 | a    | 330p.html  | 645c1.html    |
|  8 | 19/05/2020 17.47 | a    | 645c1.html | 318c1.html    |
+----+------------------+------+------------+---------------+
```

---

**Desired Output**

Notice that hit ids 2,3 and 7,8 have switched

```
+----+------------------+------+------------+---------------+-------+
| id |    timestamp     | user |    path    | previous_path | order |
+----+------------------+------+------------+---------------+-------+
|  1 | 19/05/2020 17.38 | a    | 8511p.html | (entrance)    |     1 |
|  3 | 19/05/2020 17.39 | a    | 398s1.html | 8511p.html    |     2 |
|  2 | 19/05/2020 17.39 | a    | 8511p.html | 398s1.html    |     3 |
|  4 | 19/05/2020 17.44 | a    | 398s1.html | 8511p.html    |     4 |
|  5 | 19/05/2020 17.46 | a    | 406s1.html | 398s1.html    |     5 |
|  6 | 19/05/2020 17.46 | a    | 318c1.html | 406s1.html    |     6 |
|  8 | 19/05/2020 17.47 | a    | 645c1.html | 318c1.html    |     7 |
|  7 | 19/05/2020 17.47 | a    | 330p.html  | 645c1.html    |     8 |
+----+------------------+------+------------+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: You most likely need to .sort_values by multiple columns. Can you state the rule or rationale by  what  the rows switch

Comment: The rule is that the `previous_path` should be equal to the `path` of the previous record

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood you well. Let me know if this works

```
df['previous_path']=df['path'].shift(1)
df.sort_values(by='id', ascending= True,inplace=True)
```

[image]

Comment: That's sort of what I want to do, but without changing the values of 'path' or 'previous_path'.
Hit ids 2 and 3 have the same timestamp but are in the wrong order as the previous_path of hit id 3 is not equal to the path of hit id 2.